# MOSAIC: Black grid lines between GEOTIFFs Using gdal_merge with Python

Tags: python, gdal, geotiff-tiff, mosaic

[image]

I've been trying to map an area of 35 images. Since they were in UTM I converted to Mercator projection using `gdalwarp`. I then tried to merge the images with the command:

```
gdal_merge -init 255 -o I:\newfilename.tif --optfile imagelist.txt
```

which produced a mosaic that had missing data where each image would have overlapped, similar to black grid lines.

I made sure that the order of images in my text file was arranged in order but can't figure out what else it could be. I'm completely new to coding so anything helps.

Comment: Can you show us a screen shot? It sounds like you're experiencing similar to https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/63004/what-is-the-correct-way-to-merge-adjoining-raster-images/63231#63231. Try GDALbuildVRT to build a virtual raster instead, be sure to specify -a_nodata and -s_nodata, view in QGIS or ArcGIS and when you're happy GDAL_Translate -of GTIFF your.vrt i:\newfilename.tif

Comment: Ok thank you ill give that a try! I just posted a picture.

Comment: I do have a few images that I clipped the missing data portion from using ArcGIS. Should I use the original images instead when merging?

Comment: It looks fairly similar to the related question. To screenshot, activate your window (click on the top bar), press Ctrl+PrtScn then paste into paint (or other editor), crop if needed, save and upload.

Comment: I see from your screen shot you have ArcGIS, have you considered a mosaic dataset? http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009t00000037000000 you can create a mosaic dataset and use it as you would a mosaiced raster without having to physically combine the images. Should you need to combine the images for a non-Esri package you can use Copy Raster http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000094000000 to export a mosaic dataset to a single raster.